# Rails filter when param is present for large model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

[This blog post](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/) explains how to filter based on the parameters that are present with this code.

```
def index
  @products = Product.where(nil) # creates an anonymous scope
  @products = @products.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @products = @products.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
  @products = @products.starts_with(params[:starts_with]) if params[:starts_with].present?
end
```

The `Product.where(nil)` part of the solution is problematic because it will load everything into memory and cause your server to crash if the model is big.

One of the blog post commenters said "Isn't it better to use `Product.none` instead of `Product.where(nil)`?" but I couldn't get that solution to work.

[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756101/rails-filter-based-on-multiple-params) accesses the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object via the `joins` method.  I'm not doing a join, so this solution won't work for me.

Let me know if there is a better way to do this or a completely different way I should approach this problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like:

```
def index
  [:status, :location, :starts_with].each do |param_sym|
    @products = (@products ? @products : Product).send(param_sym, params[param_sym]) if params[param_sym].present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `.all` and merge in additional scopes?

```
def filter_by_params
  params.slice(:status, :location, :starts_with)
    .compact # removes keys with nil values
    # iterates though the hash and returns a scope
    .each_with_object(Product.all) do |(key, value), scope|
      scope.merge(Product.send(key, value))
    end
end
```

Comment: @max - Will `Product.all` load everything into memory similar to `Product.where(nil)`?

Comment: Should it be `scope = scope.merge(Product.send(key, value))`

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you do `each_with_object(Product.all) do |(key, value), scope|`? Just wondering if that's a thing that would work.

Comment: @Powers ´.all´ is lazy loading as is ´.where(nil)´. I think you may have been mislead by running the commands in the rails console where the behaviour is different.