# Get all records greater than created at rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get all records of matching wiht query, I get multiple params and save them in query like that

```
query = Hash.new
query[:user_id] = params["user_id"] if query["user_id"]
query[:vehicle] = params["vehicle_id"] if query["vehicle_id"]
trips = Trip.where(query)
```

I also want to add `params['created_at]` if these params are present but no idea how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could add a scope to your Trip model.

```
scope :created_after, ->(time) { where("created_at > ?", time) if time }
```

Then chain it like so:

```
Trip.created_after(params["created_at"]).where(query)
```

Not the most elegant, but it will work. If "created_at" is not in the params, it will be nil and will just return all trips.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and riffing off the answer provided by Paul Byrne and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017124/rails-filter-when-param-is-present-for-large-model/49017379?noredirect=1#comment85101497_49017379), perhaps something like:

```
params.slice(:user_id, :vehicle_id).compact.
  each_with_object(Trip.created_after(params[:created_at])) do |(key, value), scope|
    scope.merge(Trip.send(key, value))
  end
```